# How to get the chapter title in a single page - titlesec

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, titlesec

Because of my thesis `report` style, I want to have the chapter title in a single page. I'm working with `titlesec` package.

I used `\clearpage` and `\newpage` to solve this, but doesn't work.
I also used `\titlespacing`, but without good results for different size of titles.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter}
{{%
   \filcenter\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}
   \fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont\thechapter%
 }%
}
{5pt}
{\Huge\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}%
 \parbox{\textwidth-\widthof{\LARGE\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \setcounter{chapter}{21}

  \chapter{Chapter Title}
  \section{Section one}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Section two}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{Section one}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\chapter{Chapter Title}\newpage`.

Comment: @Sigur's answer works for me. But how to align the title at the center of the page? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have the chapter heading to appear on a page of its own, add a `\clearpage` in the last optional argument for `\titleformat`. To have the heading vertically centered, add `\vfill` before and `after` the title is typeset:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vfill\filcenter}
{{%
   \filcenter\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}
   \fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont\thechapter%
 }%
}
{5pt}
{\Huge\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}%
 \parbox{\textwidth-\widthof{\LARGE\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}}%
}[\vfill\clearpage]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

  \setcounter{chapter}{21}

  \chapter{Chapter Title}
  \section{Section one}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Section two}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{Section one}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To prevent these settings from affecting the ToC, LoF and LoT, you might also need a definition using the `numberless` key to apply to those unnumbered chapters:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\filcenter}
{{%
 }%
}
{5pt}
{\Huge\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it could be possible to get that title centred vertically in the page I place? Because, `\titlespacing` wouldn't fit well for variable size of titles.

Comment: @Isai sure, please see my updated answer.